# Output of parsing code is not all similar. not sure if parsing NCBI nucleotide xml synchronously

Tags: xml, parsing, bioinformatics, biopython

```
from Bio import Entrez
accessions = ['NM_001195662','NM_001289467','NM_008866']
list1 = []
for i in accessions:
    Entrez.email = "A.N.Other@example.com"
    handle = Entrez.efetch(db="nucleotide", id= i , rettype='gb', retmode='xml')
    record = Entrez.read(handle)
    #print record
    dict1= record[0]["GBSeq_feature-table"]
    dict2 = dict1[1]["GBFeature_quals"]
    insert = []
    insert.append(i)
    insert.append(dict2[0]['GBQualifier_value'])
    insert.append(dict2[2]['GBQualifier_value'])
    insert1 = tuple(insert)
    #print insert1
    list1.append(insert1)
print list1
```

Output:

```
[('NM_001195662', 'Rp1', 'retinitis pigmentosa 1 (human)'), ('NM_001289467', 'Sox17', 'GeneID:20671'), ('NM_008866', 'Lypla1', 'lysophospholipase 1')]
```

I am trying to take a list of accession numbers from a given source put that into a list and from that acquire the gene symbol and gene name and append those to a list in the order gene accession, gene symbol, and gene name. However when parsing the data from the NCBI nucleotide xml the output is not the same for each query; giving me a GeneID where there is supposed to be a gene name. How do I ensure all of my output is universally formatted?

Comment: Did the answer solve your problem?

Comment: It definitely did. I appreciate it. Sorry for not responding sooner.

Comment: No problem at all. Glad it worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing this line of code

```
insert.append(dict2[2]['GBQualifier_value'])
```

with

```
for j in range(len(dict2)):
    if dict2[j].get('GBQualifier_name') == 'note':
        insert.append(dict2[j]['GBQualifier_value'])
```

The gene name is hiding in the section which is labeled `note`, by iterating through the sections until you get to note you should always get right gene name.

---

Side note:
If you run it for a lot of sequences, try merging `dict1` and `dict2`, you only need `dict1` to create `dict2`.